# Is possible to keep Application reporting user location?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I’m developing an application for iPhone that require server to be always aware of the user location. Does iOS have a feature whereby application (or iPhone device) keep reporting it’s location to external server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the "Tracking the User's Location" section in the [iOS App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20). It tells you how to retrieve location data in the background. In this case, you probably only want to get [significant updates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW8).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [`startUpdatingLocation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html), then do whatever you want (e.g. a POST request) in the delegate.